# NSMutableDictionary EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, singleton, nsmutabledictionary

I know there are many questions about this topic but non of them work for me because mine is a little weird.

First of all I create a static singleton class. and declare a variable of NSMutableDictionary

```
static NSMutableDictionary* mydic
@implementation mySingleton

-(mySingleton*)getInstance
{
    static mySingleton *sharedInstance;
    @synchronized(self)
    {
       if(!sharedInstance)
       {
          sharedInstance = [[mySingleton alloc] init];
          mydic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
       }
       return sharedInstance;
    }
}

-(NSMutableDictionary*)getDictionary
{
   return myDic;
}
```

then I call this NSMutableDictionary from another class like the below.

```
NSMutableDictionary* singletonDictionary = [[mySingleton getInstance] getDictionary];

MyOtherClass* myclass = [singletonDictionary objectForKey:key];// Key is NSString
// Here I can see whole the values I added to myClass for that key
NSArray *checkKey = [singletonDictionary allKeys];
for(int i = 0; i < [singletonDictionary count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[checkKey objectAtIndex:i]);// here I can see my key is there
}

[singletonDictionary removeObjectForKey:key];// here it crashes EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I am gonna get crazy about this problem. If someone has an idea please share it with me.

**EDIT :**

```
MyOtherClass * myinstance = [[MyOtherClass alloc] init];
// Fill up the instance with the desired variable here
// Forexample
// myinstance.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myInstanceName"];
.
.
.

[[[mySingleton getInstance] getDictionary] setObject:myinstance forKey:key]// key is an NSString*
[myinstance release];
```

Thanks for help.

Omer Faruk KURT

Comment: Would you please also post your code which added object into the Dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

So many problems, where to start...?

At least, it seems your `getInstance` method is not returning anything; it should probably return `mySingleton`. This could explain your `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS`, as `singletonDictionary` is probably `nil` as things stand.

Your singleton instantiation is wrong too - you need to check if the singleton has already been created, and return it if it has. Otherwise you can reallocate singletons, which is absurd.

Static references are poor design here, better to subclass and declare members in the header file.

This might fix your problems, but you're clearly jumping in at the deep end and you're going to encounter more trouble. I think you need to find good examples of code in texts or online and study those. If you do that pretty soon you'll learn the ropes.

Comment: Sorry but I am using another computer to implement and i just write the above code without care. so I did not check it. actuall I return the instance and check if it was allocated before. that is not the issue I think I will edit it for you again. sorry I was so urgent to ask the question so I made some mistakes. :)

Answer (score 0):

The NSMutableDictionary retains objects added to the dictionary. When the objects are removed they are released. As a result, removing an object from the dictionary accesses the object. If you have previously released the object and it is dealloc'ed, then this can cause an exception to be raised. If you examine the state of the object prior to removing from the dictionary you will likely see that it has already been released and dealloced.

Comment: So in this scenerio if I get the object with objectForKey and then release the object actually the object in the dictionary will be released? So is it acceptable to get the same count for the dictionary objects before releaseing the object it contains and after that moment? EDIT : I did not release any object I got from the dictionary.

Comment: objectForKey returns the same object that is in the dictionary. Following the rules you would not send release to that object unless you retained the object after getting the pointer. If you release an object in the dictionary it does not affect the count of items in the dictionary; however, if that release is not matched with a retain then you will just end up with an exception when the dictionary tries to remove the object.

Comment: I check out the code again and again. the only place I release an object is the object after I added to the dictionary. I mean after I setAnObject:object forKey:key, I release [object release]. That is the only place I release the object. I call objectForKey: and right after it removeObjectForKey:.I mean right on the following line and objectForkey: has no problem and removeObjectForKey: make it crash. It seemed so weird to me. FYI I wrote this code on a static library and I am using it in another project. Could this effect the crash? I am so desperate about this crash...

Comment: I am not sure about the static library stuff. One thought to experiment would be to comment out your release after you add the object to the dictionary. I know that if you alloc/init it is your object to release, but this could help test whether or not it is a reference counting issue or not.